# Error reading data from the connection Firebird

Tags: c#, firebird, azure-cloud-services

We are working on migrating data from different source systems(Firebird, Oracle, SQL Server) to one target system (SQL Server).

We are getting *Error reading data from the connection* exception from Firebird connections.

Code we are using

> Static DbFactory Class  to Create SourceSystem Object

```
public static class DbFactory
{
    public static DbManager CreateDb(SourceDbType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case SourceDbType.Sql:
                return new SqlDbManager();
            case SourceDbType.FireBird:
                return new FireBirdDbManager();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public enum SourceDbType
{
    Sql, FireBird
}
```

> Base DbManager Class

```
public abstract class DbManager
{
    private DbConnection m_DbConnection;
    public virtual DbConnection DbConnection
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_DbConnection == null)
            {
                m_DbConnection = new SqlConnection();
            }
            return m_DbConnection;
        }
        set
        {
            this.m_DbConnection = value;
        }
    }



    public virtual void SetConnectionString(Migration migration, DataTable dtConnectionDetails = null)
    {
        try
        {
            DbConnection.ConnectionString = string.Format("Server={0};Database={1};User ID={2};Password={3};",
           migration.NetworkPartnerData.Server,
           migration.NetworkPartnerData.Database,
           migration.NetworkPartnerData.User,
          AESEncryptionDecryptionUtility.DecodeBase64(migration.NetworkPartnerData.Password));
        }
        catch
        {

            throw;
        }


    }

    public virtual void SetConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            DbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }
        catch
        {

            throw;
        }


    }

    public virtual DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string ConnectionString, string queryText)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

> FireBirdDbManager class inherited from DbManager

```
 public class FireBirdDbManager : DbManager
{
    private FbConnection fbconnection;
    public override DbConnection DbConnection
    {
        get
        {
            if (fbconnection == null)
            {
                fbconnection = new FbConnection();
            }
            return fbconnection;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fbconnection = value as FbConnection;
        }
    }

    public override void SetConnectionString(Migration migration, DataTable connectionDetails)
    {

        this.DbConnection.ConnectionString = string.Format("Server={0};Database={1};Port=3050;User ID={2};Password={3};Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;",
            migration.NetworkPartnerData.Server,
            migration.NetworkPartnerData.Database + BuildDatabaseName(Convert.ToString(connectionDetails.Rows[0]["CL_NBR"])) + ApplicationConstants.FIREBIRD_DBFILE_EXTENSION,
            migration.NetworkPartnerData.User,
           iMigrationTool.Common.AESEncryptionDecryptionUtility.DecodeBase64(migration.NetworkPartnerData.Password));
    }
    public override DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string ConnectionString, string queryText)
    {
        using (var connection = new FbConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {


                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                connection.Open();
                using (FbTransaction readTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
                {
                    FbCommand readCommand = new FbCommand();
                    try
                    {
                        readCommand.CommandText = queryText;
                        readCommand.Connection = connection;
                        readCommand.Transaction = readTransaction;
                        FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter(readCommand);
                        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        da.Fill(dt);

                        readTransaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        readTransaction.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        readTransaction.Dispose();
                        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                        connection.Dispose();
                    }
                    return dt;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                int errorCode = ex.HResult;
                Logger.LogApplicationException(ex, null, "ERRORCODE:" + errorCode + "ConnectionString:" + ConnectionString, "MigrationWorker");
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception Images
[image: Exception Image1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Connection String built]

We are getting exception after running 3 to 4 migrations. If I restart the service again we are able to run 3 to 4 migrations.

Code we use to call the respective source systems:
[image: Create SourceSytemOjbect]

We are very new to Firebird database systems and unable to solve the problem. On a side note we are using Visual Studio 2012, Azure Cloud service

Comment: "error reading data from the connection" usually means that the connection was closed unexpectedly or otherwise generates low level IO errors. Which Firebird version are you using, and which database connection library and version? Also try disabling connection pooling.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for  your inputs . I need to check with Offshore team because we are connecting to Firebird server using FlameRobin Database Admin. we are using Library DLL : FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient and Version: 4.8.0.0, Removed connection pooling and inprocess of testing

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Still same problem no luck :( Any other suggestions

Comment: @MarkRotteveel We are using LI-V2.0.7.13318 Firebird 2.0 version server mode is classic and Linux OS. I need help guys still facing the problem :(

Comment: The only other suggestion I can give you is to upgrade to a newer Firebird version (2.5.4).

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, it looks like the server process (which for Classic is per connection) crashes. This might be related to using UDFs with bugs, but it might also be caused by bugs in Firebird itself. Since 2.0.7 there have been quite a number of Firebird releases with bug fixes for server crashes. You might also want to check the firebird.log of the server.

Comment: I have the same problem when upgrading from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6 (Fb Core provider from v7.5.0 to 9.0.1).there is no error in firebird.log,tried all sugestion with no fix .it works fine if I revert to .NET 3.1

Comment: https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/NETProvider/issues/1021

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We were able to reproduce the issue for Firebird 2.1.3.18185 by killing the Firebird task via the Task-Manager during executing a query via ADO.NET data provider (version 4.7.0). After that, we were always receiving the following exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred 
while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. 
    ---> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException: Error reading data from 
    the connection.
    ---> FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: Error reading 
    data from the connection. at 
    FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsTransaction.BeginTransaction(Transa
    ctionParameterBuffer tpb) in c: Users Jiri Documents devel NETProvider 
    working NETProvider src FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Client Managed 
    Version10 GdsTransaction.cs:line 162 at 
    FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.BeginTransaction(Transacti
    onParameterBuffer tpb) in c: Users Jiri Documents devel NETProvider working 
    NETProvider src FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Client Managed Version10 
    GdsDatabase.cs:line 571 at 
    FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbTransaction.BeginTransaction() in c: Users 
    Jiri Documents devel NETProvider working NETProvider src 
    FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient FirebirdClient FbTransaction.cs:line 363 
— End of inner exception stack trace —
```

In our case, the problem was solved and verified by disabling connection pooling (connection-string: '...;Pooling=false'). Interesting for us was the fact that according to [1] this is expected behavior when using connection pooling where the connection has been disconnected between several requests.

I hope this answer will help somebody else. This solution is also working with current ADO.NET 5.0.5 in our case.

Best regards,
Thomas

[1] http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-585?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Comment: Disabling connection pooling (connection-string: '...;Pooling=false') Did the TRICK . Thank you :)

Comment: I ran into this problem too. It is sad that there is no fix for that after that we are in version 5.12 of the ADO.net component!!

Comment: **Warning:** depends on architecture of application but disabling pooling is not good option for every application because every time when you are opening the new connection it takes significant amount of time. The better solution is to set `connection.ConnectionLifeTime = 60` seconds (or so) and let the pool manager manage old connections.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error. I have a program working with Firebird 2.5.9 written using Delphi 10.3 and Fibplus 7.6. Recently I migrated this program to Lazarus using IBX library. Now I just returned from absence live and found that Delphi program after connect to Firebird database refuses to open any datasets returning subject error, but Lazarus program works fine. But within office network with backup server on one of workstations both programs work fine.  Thank you for the tip, I'l try to change configuration parameters.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32142304)

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when execute query that length > **max query length**

in FireBird 4.x i get Error reading data from the connection
after update to 6.6 i get new error "**335544721** : Unable to complete network request to host..."

it was fixed by split query to some less query

(default 8191 characters when using UTF-8)